# JUnit 4 on Eclipse luna

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

How can I install JUnit 4 on luna eclipse . JUnit 3 working normally , but when I am doing a test with JUnit 4  at lines with annotations displays me 'The method xxx is not API '/

Comment: Add the `JUnit 4` jar to your classpath

Comment: I have no problems running junit4 in Luna. I remember a few years ago I had to delete old run configurations after migrating from junit3 to junit4.

Answer (score 0):

[JUNIT LUNA](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-junit.htm) and make sure the jar is in the classpath by looking at the build path.